# smaller subcaption

Tags: fonts, subcaption

I want a smaller subcaption so I used the following:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subcaption}{\scriptsize}
```

But this doesn't change anything except the captionlabel is thick.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you load `caption`, which is the case when you load `subcaption`, it takes over KoMa-script features.

In order to change the font size in subcaptions, you need to set the `size` key.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{labelfont={sf,bf}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{size=scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\rule{3cm}{0pt}}
\caption{Subfigure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\centering
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\rule{3cm}{0pt}}
\caption{Subfigure}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The default value for size is `smaller`, which means that it uses one size smaller than the font size in main captions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
```

after `\begin{figure}`

Comment: Please provide more detail here. Include, for example, a minimal example that shows how this does work. Also, there's probably no need to include this "after `\begin{figure}`, since consistency in a document suggests you should perform this action to *all* figures, and therefore include it in the preamble.

Comment: So this doesn't work. If I add it into preamble.. still all subcaptions and captions are as big as the other text..

Comment: Even if I put it after begin{figure} it doesn't work..